# Levenshtein Distance vs Damerau Levenstein vs Optimal String Alignment Distance

Tags: string-theory

Could anyone explain the differences between **Levenshtein Distance vs Damerau Levenstein vs Optimal String Alignment Distance**?

And the Math behind calculating distance between the strings